# Problems running deployed apps on Google AppEngine

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I have written a web application to run on Google AppEngine using the Restlet framework, communicating using json with web clients. Those work as expected. However, one specific resource written to provide response to an Android client doesn't work when accessed through Android. However, it does work when accessed through a web browser (I do not send the request parameters from the browser and thus get a 400 which is ok in this case).

This code works when running on the DevAppServer:

```
public class PlayResource extends ServerResource {
private final float SCOREBASE = 1000.0F;

@Get
@Post
public JsonRepresentation play() {
    try {
        JsonRepresentation rep = new JsonRepresentation(getRequestEntity());
        JSONObject inputJson = rep.getJsonObject();
        JSONObject outputJson = new JSONObject();

        String country = inputJson.optString("country");
        outputJson.put("country", doSomething("country",country));
                    ......
        ......
        return new JsonRepresentation(outputJson);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_BAD_REQUEST);
            return new JsonRepresentation(
                    new JSONObject()
                        .put(Messages.TYPE_ERROR, Messages.BAD_REQUEST));
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            setStatus(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        try {
            setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_BAD_REQUEST);
            return new JsonRepresentation(
                    new JSONObject()
                        .put(Messages.TYPE_ERROR, Messages.BAD_FORMAT));
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            setStatus(Status.SERVER_ERROR_INTERNAL);
            return null;
        }
    }
}

}
```

and the client Android device is running this code:

```
  Client client = new Client(Protocol.HTTP);
    try {
        JsonRepresentation requestJSON = new JsonRepresentation(new JSONObject()
            .put("country", country.trim())
        );
        Request req = new Request(Method.GET,"http://****.appspot.com/resource/play",requestJSON);
        Response resp = client.handle(req);
        String res = resp.getEntity().getText();
        JSONObject resultJSON = new JSONObject(res);
```

Running this request just hangs the Android client, the server doesn't write any log messages whatsoever suggesting the request doesn't arrive there.

Comment: Non-responsive App Engine apps are usually caused by misconfigured app.yaml descriptions and/or missing handlers. Can you include both of those here? It would help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's more a Appengine/Java issue than an android issue, but...let's try something else:

instead of using Client and the stuff u are using, first just try to see what the server responds to the simplest connection (as you do in a web browser):

```
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://yourappid.appspot.com/resource/play");
            String content = (String) url.getContent();
            System.out.println(content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If it works and you get your expeted 400, if so...try to send an httppostrequest with the data...like this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpUriRequest httpRequest = new HttpPost("http://yourappid.appspot.com/resource/play");
//set the content type to json
httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
//get and work with the response
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpRequest);
```

Let me know if the answer was useful